# Can someone identify this jellyfish?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, bioluminescence

Recently, I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaX6BK66v9A) but I couldn't find out if it's CGI or if it's an actual jellyfish. If it's real, what explains its beautiful bioluminescence pattern? And could the output from the ROV thrusters rip it apart (in the video description it says so)?

**Photo**:
[image: Screenshot from the video]

**Location**: off the East coast of Africa.

**Size**: unknown, but it can be compared to the objects in the surroundings.

**Additional info**: footage taken in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The video you linked to, and from which you got the still shot. is real.  There are  hundreds of such videos now that [Underwater Remotely Operated Vehicles](https://www.deeptrekker.com/resources/underwater-rovs) (ROV) are more commonplace.

> ...could the output from the ROV thrusters rip it apart(?)

A working class ROV needed for deep ocean floor exploration can be the size of an SUV. There's no reason to believe its thrusters can't generate the shear forces needed to (sadly) tear a delicate jelly apart.

> ...I couldn't find out if it's CGI or if it's an actual jellyfish.

Although not a jellyfish, it is similar in being delicate; it's a [ctenophore](https://oceans.taraexpeditions.org/en/jdb/ctenophores-are-not-jellyfish/) or comb jelly. The refraction/bioluminescence pattern is common in ctenophores.

> And what dazzling colors these creatures display! The cilia of the ctenophores refract light in iridescent waves. Certain species are even capable of producing light, like fireflies of the sea!

For more information and videos, [this short Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEJGO1w-jog) might help. Or for a written explanation, this article, *Introduction to Ctenophora*  (https://ucmp.berkeley.edu/cnidaria/ctenophora.html) is good.